# User can't execute stored procedure despite in role with permission

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, stored-procedures, role

I'm setting up a number of stored procedures and I would like to limit the users who can execute them to a specific server role. I've created my role and users like this:

```
USE [MyDB]
GO
CREATE ROLE [MyExecuters]
GO
CREATE USER [MyUser] FOR LOGIN [MyUser] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo]
GO
ALTER ROLE [MyExecuters] ADD MEMBER [MyUser]
GO
```

And I've granted permissions on the SP to the role like this:

```
USE [MyDB]
GO
GRANT EXECUTE ON [dbo].[MyProcedure] TO [MyExecuters] AS [dbo];
GO
```

However if `MyUser` tries to execute the SP, they get an access denied message. I tried explicitly granting the `EXECUTE` permission on the SP to `MyUser` (through the procedure properties in Management Studio) and now they can execute it fine. What's going on?

Comment: Have you tried the `EXECUTE AS` clause in stored procedure declaration ?

Comment: Have a look at [Granting permission with the EXECUTE AS command](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1227/granting-permission-with-the-execute-as-command-in-sql-server/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this script gives the permissions assigned to a table or stored procedure in a script format.

have a look what it returns for your `MyProcedure`
that could be a start.

```
SELECT
  (
    dp.state_desc + ' ' +
    dp.permission_name collate latin1_general_cs_as + 
    ' ON ' + '[' + s.name + ']' + '.' + '[' + o.name + ']' +
    ' TO ' + '[' + dpr.name + ']'
  ) AS GRANT_STMT
FROM sys.database_permissions AS dp
  INNER JOIN sys.objects AS o ON dp.major_id=o.object_id
  INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS s ON o.schema_id = s.schema_id
  INNER JOIN sys.database_principals AS dpr ON dp.grantee_principal_id=dpr.principal_id
WHERE 1=1
    AND o.name IN ('MyProcedure')      -- Uncomment to filter to specific object(s)
--  AND dp.permission_name='EXECUTE'    -- Uncomment to filter to just the EXECUTEs
ORDER BY dpr.name
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot! My update scripts had got mixed up so the permissions kept getting removed without me noticing.